# How to pass JTextField[][] as arg to dynamic loaded java class method?

Tags: java, swing, exception, reflection, invoke

I have a JComboBox with dynamic loaded java classes via classLoader. After creating object I want to pass to one of it's methods JTextField[][[] as arg.

```
final JTextField[][] gameFields = new JTextField[12][12];

Object runtimeStrategyObject = strategyClass.newInstance();
Method method = strategyClass.getDeclaredMethod("move",JTextField[][].class);
method.invoke(runtimeStrategyObject, gameFields);
```

Method I want to call

```
public void move(JTextArea[][] gameFields) {
    // method body
}
```

Problem is that I get "NoSuchMethodException". Any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `move(JTextArea[][] gameFields)` method has `JTextArea[][].class` as parameter type. So the correct way should be either trying to get the function with `getDeclaredMethod` by passing the `JTextArea[][].class` as parameter type:

```
Method method = strategyClass.getDeclaredMethod("move", JTextArea[][].class);
```

Or, Changing the `move` method parameter type to `JTextField[][]`:

```
public void move(JTextField[][] gameFields) {
    // method body
}
```

check out the documentation: [`getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

Comment: Thank you so much...I don't know how this mislook could happen. It's the same feeling when you are searching for complex error and suddenly you discover you forgot about semicolon... Thanks once again!

Comment: :) It is ok. It happens all the time. That is why we are here to help each other. Make sure to check the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to know how stack overflow works.

Comment: @chris.rave: if Sage's answer answered your original question, then please don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the large check-mark next to the answer.